# Need a quick javascript function to validate the Text in Texarea "QCC" "

Tags: javascript

Need a quick javascript function to validate the Text in Texarea = "QCC"

> style="top:14px; left:0px; width:177px; height:21px;" arautocak="0" >arautoctt="400" arencryptdataatrest="0" rows="1" wrap="off">QCC

Comment: The example code is incomplete. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

To do any sort of validation, the textarea will need at minimum a NAME attribute, preferably an ID attribute.

See this answer with working fiddle

[textarea validation with fiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060131/jquery-validate-plugin-input-vs-textarea)